# How to get account historical balances?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, accounts, history

how would I go about obtaining a list of historical data (tokens held, their quantities and a timestamp) for an address? The [stellar expert](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/) explorer has a way of generating this kind of data, an example can be seen [here](https://api.stellar.expert/api/explorer/public/account/GAGA7RRXJ3PBP2COTU7O5FMNDDZUXWVO7RWYWR2XODEAZVRJAWZEYMQ4?ts=2018-06-15).
Could this be obtained from the public horizon endpoint or a stellar core instance or is it a bit more involved (if yes where should I start looking?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run aggregation query over the `history_effects` "replaying" all effects for the account (don't forget to join `history_transactions` to sum up tx fees). But you won't get the **precise** balances as [Horizon currently ignores failed transactions](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/309), therefore there is no way to determine how much XLM were spent on the failed transactions fees based on the information available in Horizon db.

The only way to calculate balances precisely is to parse Stellar archives (or XDR records stored in Core database) [directly](https://www.lumenauts.com/blog/dark-archeology-digging-through-stellar-xdr-archives).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the historical balance directly, but it is possible.

The endpoints ["transaction effects"](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/effects) and ["transaction for accounts"](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/transactions) could help you to deduce the actions and changes on certain accounts.